# Get Rx and Tx value from slurm network moniter command

Tags: linux, grep, network-monitoring

i have found `slurm -s -i eth0` and `bmon` command which is very help full

i need a way to get the value of Current Rx and Tx

i used grep but it didnt help at all.

EDIT:
command `top` has an option -n for number of iterations which we can set to 1
we can also save this to an output file or even use grep command and get desired output as our need, but is there a way to do the same with `slurm` or `bmon` command

Answer (score 0):

You could just use ifconfig:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep 'RX bytes' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f2 -d ':'
```

Divide it by `1024` or by `1024^2` if you want the values in kB or MB, respectively.